# Error 13 in for each vba outlook

Tags: vba, for-loop, outlook

I want to delete a mail when the delivered response comes. This is a fragment of my code. I don't understand why the **for each** runs into **error 13**

```
Sub test222()

Dim oapp As Outlook.Application
Dim osession As Outlook.NameSpace
Dim oInbox As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim oSentItem As Outlook.MAPIFolder

Dim omail As Outlook.MailItem
Dim conID As String

Set oapp = New Outlook.Application
Set osession = oapp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set oInbox = osession.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
Set oSentItem = osession.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderSentMail)

i = 1
For Each omail In oSentItem.Items

If (omail.Subject = "Delivered: aa") Then
     Msgbox "Hi"
     omail.Delete

     Exit For
              Else
     i = i + 1
     End If         
Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare `omail` as `Object` and check `TypeName` in the loop. The way you did it, there will be a type mismatch error when the loop runs into something else than an e-mail message, e.g. an appointment item.

Also read about late binding. I'd advise to use this functionality when you are working with non-default libraries.

Comment: Tested it, but ran into some other problems. This doesn't work on delivery receipts, only works for one time only: when I test it with some subjects, I get the msgbox, but the mail won't get deleted. When I run the macro again, nothing happens. **However the main problem is, that it doesn't work on delivered reciepts.**

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem you're running into, but I suggest checking what type the delivery receipt has. Is it a MailItem?

Comment: It is supposed to be a ReportItem it seems. I have tried this code [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/78924/when-is-a-mailitem-not-a-mailitem , but modified with: `If TypeName(msg) = ReportItem Then MsgBox "2"` in the for cycle, but it doesnt do anything.

Comment: TypeName returns a string.