# Check for the senderEmailAddress

Tags: vba, outlook, outlook-filter

I have a listener in VBA on my outlook box to perform an action if a receive a mail from a specific email.

The problem is that if I get a error mail (non-delivery email) then my condition is run on a mail which doesn't have that property so my method crashes.

I don't know what the subject may be either.

Does anyone have an idea if I can test if the property exists or if there is another property I can check for to identify if my sender matches?

Many thanks in advance

```
Sub SetFlagIcon() 

 Dim mpfInbox As Outlook.Folder 

 Dim obj As Outlook.MailItem 

 Dim i As Integer 



 Set mpfInbox = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI").GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders("Test") 

 ' Loop all items in the Inbox\Test Folder 

 For i = 1 To mpfInbox.Items.Count 

 If mpfInbox.Items(i).Class = olMail Then 

 Set obj = mpfInbox.Items.Item(i) 

 If obj.SenderEmailAddress = "someone@example.com" Then 

 'Set the yellow flag icon 

 obj.FlagIcon = olYellowFlagIcon 

 obj.Save 

 End If 

 End If 

 Next 

End Sub
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

***`Dim obj as a generic Object`*** - *there are objects other than* ***`MailItem`*** *in your Inbox, also to improve your loop try using*  ***[Items.Restrict Method (Outlook)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Outlook.Items.Restrict)***

```
Option Explicit
Sub SetFlagIcon()
    Dim mpfInbox As Outlook.Folder
    Dim obj As Object
    Dim Items As Outlook.Items
    Dim i As Long
    Dim Filter As String
    
    Set mpfInbox = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI").GetDefaultFolder _
                                    (olFolderInbox).Folders("Temp")

    Filter = "[SenderEmailAddress] = 'someone@example.com'"
    
    Set Items = mpfInbox.Items.Restrict(Filter)
    
    ' Loop all items in the Inbox\Test Folder
    For i = 1 To Items.Count
        If Items(i).Class = olMail Then
            Set obj = Items(i)
            'Set the yellow flag icon
            obj.FlagIcon = olYellowFlagIcon
            obj.Save
        End If
    Next
    
End Sub
```

---

> *<sub>[Items.Restrict Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Outlook.Items.Restrict) Applies a filter to the [Items](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Outlook.Items.Restrict) collection, returning a new collection containing all of the items from the original that match the filter.</sub>*