# MailItem.SentOn on an item in inbox generates Object doesn't support this property or method

Tags: vbscript

I want to know the mails with a particular word in the subject that were sent in the last 5 days.  Here is the code snippet.

```
For Each m In objInbox.items
    If InStr(1,UCase(m.subject), "LEAVE;",vbTextCompare) <> 0 and m.SentOn >= now-5 then
          msgbox "There is a mail sent on"&m.SentOn
    End If
Next
```

I get an error saying that 
**Object doesn't support this property or method:m.SentOn**

If I remove `m.SentOn >= now-5` condition from IF, it works as expected.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42547062/4539709

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check for the senderEmailAddress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42546891/check-for-the-senderemailaddress)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not every item in a mailbox folder is necessarily a `MailItem`.

Try adding a check on the object type before you run the check, like this:

```
For Each m In objInbox.Items
    If TypeName(m) = "MailItem" Then
        If InStr(1,UCase(m.subject), "LEAVE;",vbTextCompare) <> 0 and m.SentOn >= now-3 Then
            msgbox "There is a mail sent on" & m.SentOn
        End If
    End If
Next
```

edit: modified to `vbscript` specifically rather than `outlook-vba`

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure the item is really a `MailItem` object. In VB Script, you can either use the `TypeName` function (check for "MailItem"), or you can use the `Class` property (all OOM objects expose it). For the `MailItem` object, it will be 43.