# Detecting if Email is not a calendar invite

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I have some code that imports emails into a form. However, it gets caught up on calender invites an such. As a response, I would like to filter out all these calender invites so they are not even trying to import in the first place. This is the code i have so far:

```
    Dim SenderCheck As String
'Build the list selection box
j = 0
For i = 1 To Emails.Count
    With ListBox_Emails
    If TypeName(Item) = "MailItem" Then
    SenderCheck = Emails(i).Sender.Address
    If InStr(1, SenderCheck, "express-scripts.com") > 0 Then
        .AddItem Emails(i).Sender
        .List(j, 1) = Emails(i).Subject
        .List(j, 2) = Emails(i).ReceivedTime
        .List(j, 3) = "N"
        j = j + 1
        Else: MsgBox "error"
        End If
    Else: MsgBox "not mail item"
    End If
            End With
    On Error GoTo TEMP
```

The issue is with the line `If TypeName(Item)="MailItem" then` as everything is now deemed not a mail item and I get the "Not a mail item" error.

How would I go about fixing this issue? I think the syntax is incorrect but I can not figure out how to correct it.

Comment: Perhaps unrelated to your main question, but did you mean to tag this question as "excel" and not "outlook"? Also, what is `Item`? You are using `Emails(i)` everywhere else in the loop.

Comment: @BigBen yes this is within an excel file. Also, that was just a recent typo. Even with `Emails(i)` in there it doesn't filter correctly.

Comment: Can you share the rest of your code, for better context?

Comment: Use olMail Class - Example https://stackoverflow.com/a/42547062/4539709 or Value 43, [sid](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56778847/4539709) answer should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works just fine for me. It skips the calendar invites

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim oMail As Object, Item As Object
    Dim objNS As Object, olFolder As Object

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set objNS = OutApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set olFolder = objNS.GetDefaultFolder(6) '<~~ olFolderInbox = 6

    For Each Item In olFolder.Items
        'https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.olobjectclass
        If Item.Class = 43 Then
            Set oMail = Item
            Debug.Print oMail.Subject
            Debug.Print oMail.SenderEmailAddress
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Siddarth's answer is still correct and helped me today,
I would prefer olMail as it is more readable than 43.

Comment: In that case just declare `Private Const olMail as Integer = 43` on top and then you can use `If Item.Class = olMail Then`. This is required because we are late binding with Outlook. If we were Early Binding then I would have used `olMail` instead of 43 :)