# How to save attachments from selected Outlook conversations with VBA

Tags: vba, outlook

The logic is as follows:

- Loop through selected messages.
- Loop through attachments of selected messages.
- Save attachments to pre-defined folder.

I am experiencing Runtime error 13.

I'm unsure which types are mismatched.

```
Public Sub SaveAttachments()
    Dim objOL As Outlook.Application
    Dim objMsg As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim objAttachments As Outlook.Attachments
    Dim objSelection As Outlook.Selection
    Dim i As Long
    Dim lngCount As Long
    Set objOL = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set objSelection = objOL.ActiveExplorer.Selection
    For Each objMsg In objSelection
        Set objAttachments = objMsg.Attachments
        lngCount = objAttachments.Count
        If lngCount > 0 Then
            For i = 1 To lngCount
                If objAttachments.Item(i).Type <> 5 Then
                    objAttachments.Item(i).SaveAsFile "C:\Users\Danny\Desktop\Attachments\" & objAttachments.Item(i).FileName
                End If
            Next i
        End If
    Next objMsg
ExitSub:
        Set objAttachments = Nothing
        Set objMsg = Nothing
        Set objSelection = Nothing
        Set objOL = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: What line throws the error? Do you have any items that aren't `MailItem`s (appointments, tasks, etc)?

Comment: I was highlighting some appointments i guess

Comment: ok if i select only messages it works. thanks man :)

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78924/when-is-a-mailitem-not-a-mailitem

Answer (score 1):

The `Selection` object may contain different Outlook item types - `AppointmentItem`, `TaskItem`, `DocumentItem`, i.e. not only the `MailItem` ones. So, I'd suggest declaring the item as `object` instead and then check out the message class or its type:

```
Dim individualItem As Object
For Each individualItem In Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection
    'Perform some action on individualItem
Next Message
```