# Fetch Outlook emails into Excel

Tags: vba, outlook

I am trying to export Outlook emails into Excel. The code below, for some unknown reason to me, is only exporting 21 mail items. What am I doing wrong?

The array olItems has 1140 items in the count. I don't understand why the control is breaking out of the loop after 21 items.

```
Option Explicit

Sub list_email_info()

Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
Dim xlwb As Excel.Workbook
Dim i As Long
Dim arrHeader As Variant

Dim oINS As NameSpace
Dim oIInboxFolder As MAPIFolder
Dim olItems As Items
Dim olMailItem As MailItem

arrHeader = Array("Date Created", "Subject", "Sender's Name", "Unread")

Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
xlApp.Visible = True
Set xlwb = xlApp.Workbooks.Add

Set oINS = GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set oIInboxFolder = oINS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders("OST")
Set olItems = oIInboxFolder.Items

i = 1

On Error Resume Next
xlwb.worksheets(1).Range("A1").Resize(1, UBound(arrHeader) + 1).Value = arrHeader

For Each olMailItem In olItems

    xlwb.worksheets(1).cells(i + 1, "A").Value = olItems(i).CreationTime
    xlwb.worksheets(1).cells(i + 1, "B").Value = olItems(i).Subject
    xlwb.worksheets(1).cells(i + 1, "C").Value = olItems(i).SenderName
    xlwb.worksheets(1).cells(i + 1, "D").Value = olItems(i).UnRead

    i = i + 1
Next olMailItem

MsgBox "Done"
xlwb.worksheets(1).cells.entirecolumn.autofit




Set xlwb = Nothing
Set xlApp = Nothing

Set olItems = Nothing
Set oIInboxFolder = Nothing
Set oINS = Nothing


End Sub
```

@Ben - I have modified as suggested, I am still getting the Type Mismatch Error

[image]

@Ben - Below error when I try to "Run" the code in the editor. This was not happening earlier.

[image]

Comment: Comment out `On Error Resume Next`. Do you get an error, and what is the error message?

Comment: It's very possible that you have items in that folder that are not `MailItem`s: [When is a MailItem not a MailItem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78924/when-is-a-mailitem-not-a-mailitem)

Comment: So, I commented out On Error Resume Next. When I watch the "olItems", it errors out as "Type mismatch" because oIItems =nothing. But, then when I press the "Run" button in the IDE, the control catches up with the next item in the loop.

Comment: You want to test if the item is a `MailItem`.

Comment: Where would I do that? Something interesting also is happening and I do not know if they are related but the watch window variables are disappearing when this error 13 (Type mismatch) occurs.

Comment: I will check this now.

Comment: The answer from this link does not help.

Comment: That answer does *exactly* the same thing as mine. It uses `TypeOf` to test the type of the item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are other types of items besides `MailItem`s - see [When is a MailItem not a MailItem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78924/when-is-a-mailitem-not-a-mailitem).

First, remove `On Error Resume Next`. That is just hiding potential errors.

Second, change your loop to something like this:

```
Dim itm as Object
For Each itm In olItems
    If TypeOf itm Is MailItem Then
        Set olMailItem = itm
        xlwb.worksheets(1).cells(i + 1, "A").Value = olMailItem.CreationTime
        xlwb.worksheets(1).cells(i + 1, "B").Value = olMailItem.Subject
        xlwb.worksheets(1).cells(i + 1, "C").Value = olMailItem.SenderName
        xlwb.worksheets(1).cells(i + 1, "D").Value = olMailItem.UnRead

        i = i + 1   
    End If  
Next
```

Comment: This above code did the trick. What is the difference between this code and the code in the screen capture in my question?

Comment: The problem in your code is `For Each olMailItem In olItems`. That fails when the item is not a `MailItem`. The proposed answer is different: `itm` is an *Object*, not a `MailItem`.

Comment: Gotcha! Duh me.

Comment: Is there a way I could have this same piece of code work as VB macro?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Right now, I have this code in the Outlook's VB Editor and I do not know how to make it run unless I open up the editor and hit the play button. How could I make this code to run from within the Outlook? I clicked on the macro name from under the "Macros" option and nothing happens. What gives?                       ** EDIT** I think my workplace email system has macros disabled. Is that why I can run this macro on demand from within Outlook?

Comment: Should work. Are you still in `Debug` mode still?

Comment: I have closed out the editor. I only have Outlook open. I am under Developer >>Macros  and when I click  project1.list_email_info, nothing happens.

Comment: Did you see what I posted in [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203826/discussion-between-jrules80-and-bigben)?