# VBA download attachments from mails since certain date

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I am trying to write simple code to download outlook attachments and save them in disk folder. I have found one that works very well. However, I need to add another `If` so that only email SINCE certain date are saved. I am trying to use `ReceivedTime` property and date variable (defined as `rec_date`). Unfortunately, I keep getting error 438:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub btn_extractemails_Click()

Dim OlApp As Object
Dim OlMail As Object
Dim OlItems As Object
Dim OlFolder As Object
Dim j As Integer
Dim strFolder As String
Dim rec_date As Date

 

Set OlApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")

If Err.Number = 429 Then
    Set OlApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
End If


strFolder = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Extract_test"
rec_date = #8/17/2022#

Set OlFolder = OlApp.GetNamespace("MAPI").Folders("Folder1").Folders("Folder2").Folders("Folder3") '

Set OlItems = OlFolder.Items
OlItems.Sort "[ReceivedTime]"

For Each OlMail In OlItems

If OlMail.ReceivedTime >= rec_date Then
    If OlMail.Attachments.Count > 0 Then
        For j = 1 To OlMail.Attachments.Count
            OlMail.Attachments.Item(j).SaveAsFile strFolder & "\" & OlMail.Attachments.Item(j).Filename
       Next j
   End If
End If
Next

 

Set OlFolder = Nothing
Set OlItems = Nothing
Set OlMail = Nothing
Set OlApp = Nothing

 
End Sub
```

According to debugger the `If OlMail.ReceivedTime >= rec_date Then` is the line that gives the error. I wanted to keep my code as simple as possible but any working solution is welcome.

What might be important to note: this error appears even when I do simple `some_date_variable = OlMail.ReceivedTime` (same for `.SentOn`) in my code.

Comment: have you tried making your `recdate` a date time?  `dd/mm/yyyy 00:00:00`

Comment: I don't think those are the answers. I am doing something wrong: it appears `OlMail` does not have either `ReceivedTime` or `SentOn` property. The error appears even if i try to store it like a variable: `some_date_variable = OlMail.ReceivedTime` (same for `.SentOn`). I think something is wrong with the way certain objects are named, but can`t figure oue what.

Comment: Intellisense won't show for these as you've defined them as object.

Comment: Verify that the object is a mailitem before attempting to return mailitem properties. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78924/when-is-a-mailitem-not-a-mailitem

Answer (score 0):

Your code is assuming there can be only `MailItem` objects in the folder. A `ReportItem` object for one does not expose the `ReceivedTime` property.

You must first check that the Class property (all OOM objects expose it) equals 43 (`OlObjectClass.olMail`).

Secondly, do not loop through all items in a folder checking for a condition, let the store provider do the work  - use `Find/FindNext` or `Restrict` with a restriction like `"[ReceivedTime] > '8/17/2022' "`